# How to follow parent-child relationships in a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, loops, search, tree, categories

I have a classic database table for multi level categories like this (`0` means root):

```
ID - Name - Father
1    News      0
2    Articles  0
3    Politics  1
4    Politics  2
5    World     3
6    World     4
```

I have a path like this: `/News/Articles/Politics`, and I have the above table data in an array.

I begin with an `explode()` call with `/` on the path, and I've tried a few methods, but nothing is good in all cases.

Here is something I've tried:

```
$cat_path_ary = explode($cfg['categories_separator'], $cat_path);
if (count($cat_path_ary) > 1) {
    $catname = array_pop($cat_path_ary);
    $catparent = array_pop($cat_path_ary);
    $cat_id = $this->getCatIDbyName($plugin, $catname, $catparent);
} else {
   $catname = $cat_path_ary[0];
   foreach($this->root_cats($plugin) as $categories) {
      if($categories['name'] == $catname ) {
       return $categories['cid'];
      }
   }
}
```

What is the best way to traverse the path values and determine the final value's `ID`?

From `/News/Articles/Politics` I expect to return `5`.

Comment: So basically you want to traverse the tree?

Comment: basically if i have  /News/Politics/World i want a function that return the id '5'

Comment: This question is clear enough and not Too Broad.  The OP has supplied a coding attempt which is streaks better than many "gimme the codez" questions that land on this site.  I have voted to Leave Open and upvoted. This is a welcome question here, let's not disincentivize posting a question of this quality.

Comment: unfortunately, there are more people here interested in marking as a duplicate and negativizing than in helping, and thanks for edit my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rarely recommend doing iterated calls on a database and this case is no different. 
 Because your result set should be relatively small, you can afford to perform a full table query and process the multidimensional array to achieve your desired output.

Iterate the entries in your path and perform an iterated check for qualifying rows (matching `Name` and matching `Father`).

Since there can be only one qualifying row per inner loop, `break` as soon as it is found for best efficiency.  ...just be sure to update the `$id` and `$parent` variables before doing so.

A check for "no qualifying rows" has been implemented, but it may or may not be relevant to your project.  You can decide if you want this safety net.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/RGOgX))

```
$resultset = [                                                     // query just once, collect the full tree
    ["ID" => 1, "Name" => "News", "Father" => 0],
    ["ID" => 2, "Name" => "Articles", "Father" => 0],
    ["ID" => 3, "Name" => "Politics", "Father" => 1],
    ["ID" => 4, "Name" => "Politics", "Father" => 2],
    ["ID" => 5, "Name" => "World", "Father" => 3],
    ["ID" => 6, "Name" => "World", "Father" => 4]
];

$path = "/News/Politics/World";
// $path = "/Articles/The Funnies/Garfield";                        // a test case that fails
// News: parent = 0, id = 1                                         // \
// Politics: parent = 1, id = 3                                     //  > the intended logic
// World: parent = 3, id = 5                                        // /

$cfg['categories_separator'] = "/";
$breadcrumbs = explode($cfg['categories_separator'], trim($path, "/"));
// var_export($breadcrumbs);                                        // see what is generated

$parent = 0;                                                        // default value
foreach ($breadcrumbs as $crumb) {
    $id = false;                                                    // set invalid value for success check
    foreach ($resultset as $row) {
        if ($row["Name"] == $crumb && $parent == $row["Father"]) {  // qualifying match
            $id = $parent = $row["ID"];                             // dual declaration
            break;                                                  // break inner loop, progress to next $crumb        
        }
    }
    if (!$id) {                                                     // inner loop failed to find qualifying match
        echo "Uh-oh, Broken Breadcrumb Path -- $crumb not found in $path\n";
        break;                                                      // break outer loop, path is invalid
    }
    // echo "ID = $id for $crumb\n";                                // uncomment to see progress
}
echo "ID = $id for $crumb\n";                                       // echo the result
```

Output:

```
ID = 5 for World
```

Comment: I manage do it myself before sleep,  with double lines of code, extra function call, and three loops. This code is infinitely better, more elegant, and it works perfectly, thanks. Solved!